# How to EMR Auto Scale UP/DOWN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I am new with AWS EMR where I need to scale up/down my task nodes automatically based on the usage. What I am thinking to add SNS event on Cloudwatch alarm for AppPending (scale up) and isIdle ( scale down).
Am I thinking correctly? 
Is there any good documentation on this?
Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no in-built capability** within Amazon EMR to automatically scale the cluster size based upon some metric.

One method is to **add/remove Task Nodes as a Job Step**. This does not automatically scale based upon demand, but can scale when you know that a large job step is required.

For example, if the cluster is performing a batch of several job steps and one of the steps requires more servers:

- Create a job step that adds Task Nodes
- Create a job step to perform the work
- Create a job step to remove excess Task Nodes

To be truly automatic, you would need to **monitor some combination of metrics that would indicate heavy load**, and then add/remove nodes accordingly. The choice of metrics, however, would depend upon your particular workloads.

Another option is to **fire-up a cluster for specific jobs**, then terminate the cluster when the job is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Themis](https://github.com/atlassian/themis), an EMR autoscaling framework developed at Atlassian.

Current features include reactive autoscaling (based on current usage) as well as proactive autoscaling (based on predefined schedules).

The tool also comes with a simple Web UI and is very easy to configure.